# Regex substituting opening parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl, parentheses

As part of a parsing script I'm trying to convert strings like this:

```
<a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%20%282%29.pdf">
```

into

```
<a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%20(2).pdf">
```

The regex for the closing parenthesis works fine

```
perl -i -pe "s~(href\=\/?[\"\']\.\.\/$i\-(?:(?!%29).)*)%29([^\"\']*[\"\'])~\1)\2~g" "$pageName".html
```

giving me

```
    <a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%20%282).pdf">
```

**The problem** arrises with the equivalent regex for the opening parenthesis:

```
perl -i -pe "s~(href\=\/?[\"\']\.\.\/$i\-(?:(?!%28).)*)%28([^\"\']*[\"\'])~\1(\2~g" "$pageName".html
```

just returns the two groups with nothing in between:

```
<a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%202%29.pdf">
```

Escaping the ( in the substitution with a backslash (or two) has no effect. If I wrap it in some other characters (say ~\1#(#\2~g ) the parenthesis still disappears (giving me %20##2%29 ).

If however in a fit of desperation I add seven parenthesises into the substitution, it works.

```
perl -i -pe "s~(href\=\/?[\"\']\.\.\/$i\-(?:(?!%28).)*)%28([^\"\']*[\"\'])~\1(((((((\L\2~g" "$pageName".html
```

outputs

```
<a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%20(2%29.pdf">
```

Can somebody please make sense of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you have doesn't match the string you show at all. It matches something that looks like

```
<a href=/"../$i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%29xxxxxxxxxx">
```

with literal dots, and whatever `$i` contains.

Also, a couple of points about your substitution:

- Don't escape characters that don't need escaping. It may take some experience to know without checking which characters you need to escape, but the main point of using `~` as a delimiter is to avoid having to escape slashes in the regex, so at least you could have avoided that.
- Don't use `\1`, `\2` etc. in the replacement string. Perl tries very hard to make this work, but normally in Perl those sequences mean to insert the characters `\x01` and `\x02`. Use `$1` and `$2`.

So your regex could be written

```
s~(href=/?["']\.\./$i-(?:(?!%29).)*)%29([^"']*["'])~$1)$2~;
```

but it still doesn't *"work fine"* with the string you gave, which would have to look something like

```
<a href=/"../$i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%282%29xxxxxxxxxx">
```

again, containing whatever is in `$i`. I don't understand at all the optional slash before the `href` attribute value: it is invalid HTML.

However, using a string that your first regex matches, *your second one also works*, replacing opening parentheses correctly, so I can't guess at what the problem may be.

There is often no need to verify the entire string. You can just replace the parts you're interested in. So I would write something like

```
s/(href="[^"]+)%28(\d+)%29(\.pdf")/$1($2)$3/;
```

which works fine on the string you gave, and replaces both open and close parentheses at once.

Comment: Thanks. This is all good general advice. I'd tried to simplify the problem before posting it here but obviously missed the mark quite considerably. I went back and cleaned things up further and adding in more debugging and eventually traced the problem down to another rogue substitution in my script

Comment: To clarify a couple of points: $i is a variable because this is sitting within a shell script. Secondly, I know the optional slash isn't valid HTML, I'm just trying to accomodate anything the WYSISYG editor has churned out. Ultimately though the critical assessment you gave it put me in the right frame of mind to go back and reevaluate the situation several more times until I understood it. Thanks!

Comment: I gathered that `$i` was a shell variable, but I couldn't reconcile your regex with the string you claimed it matched. Any string I tried that matched the first pattern would also match the second, so I couldn't replicate your problem. There is a strong case here for writing the whole thing as a Perl script, instead of an ominous mixture of shell and Perl where no one is sure how many backslashes there should be anywhere. Perl is far more versatile than any shell, and you should focus your efforts on learning it thoroughly.

Comment: Yes. Totally agree @Borodin. The project's scope has grown from something that was a sensible little shell script into a beast that needs to be rewritten. And apologies, the input that I gave you gets modified further up in the script, by the time this substitution takes place it looks more like : href="../$i-community_events/%20Special%20event_2013_%282%29.pdf"

Comment: Fair enough. But you say you're on the right track now, and that is most important. My services are available for the migration if you're interested. Ask here and I will post a temporary email address. Otherwise I wish you well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following will be helpful or at least provide some direction. It will work on Perl version 10 and above.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.0; # For regex \K

use URI::Escape;

my $string = '<a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%20%282%29.pdf">';
$string =~ s/.+2013%20\K([^.]+)(?=\.pdf)/uri_unescape($1)/e;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://www.web.com/%20Special%20event%202013%20(2).pdf">
```

Left enough of the date and the space (`%20`) as an anchor, then used `\K` to **K**eep all of that.  Then captured the URI encoded text, which is later decoded and used as the substitution text.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it turned out the problem was elsewhere in my script (another substitution was removing the parentesis) - but \K is a handy operator to add to the arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems understanding your regex, but this might work:

```
 perl -pe "s~(href\s*=\s*\"[^\"]*)%28(.*?)%29~\$1(\$2)~g" input
```